# select colour from one object and then click on another object and change its background colour

Tags: javascript, colors, onclick

Im making a game but I'm currently stuck on a problem that I've been trying to solve for a while now. I need to select a circle which is blue and then click on a clear circle and that clear circle needs to then change its attribute background to the blue but only when i click on the clear circle.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

supposing the first circle has id "circle-1" and the second "circle-2", and supposing you specify the color of your elements using the css property "background-color", you can do the following:

```
document.querySelector('#circle-2').style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#circle-1')).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Of course you have to bind this code on click of the circle and adapt it using $(this) to select the current color in order to make it dynamic